# Why does JS throw unexpected error while re-writing a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Error is:

```
function (a){var b,c,d,e=this[0];{if(arguments.length)return d=m.isFunction(a),this.each(function(c){var e;1===this.nodeType&&(e=d?a.call(this,c,m(this).val()):a,null==e?e="":"number"==typeof e?e+="":m.isArray(e)&&(e=m.map(e,function(a){return null==a?"":a+""})),b=m.valHooks[this.type]||m.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()],b&&"set"in b&&void 0!==b.set(this,e,"value")||(this.value=e))});if(e)return b=m.valHooks[e.type]||m.valHooks[e.nodeName.toLowerCase()],b&&"get"in b&&void 0!==(c=b.get(e,"value"))?c:(c=e.value,"string"==typeof c?c.replace(lc,""):null==c?"":c)}}
```

What I am trying to do is to catch a variable on Focus Out:

```
  $('.field').focusout(function() {

    var date = $('.field').val;
    console.log(date);
    //Do something else

  });
```

The HTML for field is:

```
<input type="text" class="field" />
```

Comment: Typo... `val` is a function `val()`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.val()` ?

Comment: Oh Yeah, thanks. that thing was getting to my nerves

Answer (score 3):

Just a Typo...

`val` is a function. Use `val()`

*Yes I know this question is not worth an answer, but otherwise someone will just transplant the comment as their own answer :)*

Comment: no, it is ok, well done

Comment: Ha ha ha Nice i like these lines someone will just transplant the comment as their own answer :)